# Magick++ Bitmap::GetThumbnailImage() blocks file, unable to delete it

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

Hello fellow programmers.

First of all my C/C++ experience is only 5 weeks.
( I'm currently an intern and normally work with Java at my real job)

I am working on an application that reads .tif files and shows them to the user. After the user finished looking at the image it should be closed and deleted from the hard disk.

The problem is that I can't remove the image after closing it.
I think the image process is still running and that denies my program from deleting the file.

My guess is that Gdiplus somehow keeps the file open even though I used `delete pCloneBmp;` on the Bitmap. Does anyone have an idea or tried something similar with Gdiplus?

I tried this piece of code to delete the file (explanation in the next code block):

```
delete pCloneBmp;
delete gdiZoomedLoaded;
delete gdiOrgLoaded;
DeleteObject( bmpLoaded );
remove( filenames.at( 0 ).c_str( ) );
WORD error = GetLastError( ); 
// error codes:
// 0 == Success
// 32 == The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Here is what I tried to do:

```
// This is how I call the function.
scale_image( (Gdiplus::Bitmap*)gdiOrgLoaded , x_bmp , y_bmp , org_width_bmp , org_height_bmp , scale_bmp );

// vvv Function definition vvv
HBITMAP scale_image( Gdiplus::Bitmap *old_bmp , int x , int y , int width ,  int height , float scale )
{
HBITMAP result = NULL;
int newWidth = width * scale;
int newHeight = height * scale;

Gdiplus::RectF bmpRect( 0 , 0 , newWidth , newHeight );
Gdiplus::Bitmap *pCloneBmp = old_bmp->Clone( 0 , 0 , width , height , old_bmp->GetPixelFormat() );

// If I run the deletion code here the error code is 0
// and the file gets deleted

// vvv It seems that this line causes the problem vvv
pCloneBmp = ( Gdiplus::Bitmap* )pCloneBmp->GetThumbnailImage( newWidth , newHeight );

// If I run the deletion code here the error code is 32
// and the file won't be deleted

Gdiplus::Graphics *pGraphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage( pCloneBmp );
pGraphics->DrawImage( pCloneBmp , bmpRect , 0 , 0 , newWidth , newHeight , Gdiplus::UnitPixel );

if ( pCloneBmp )
{
    pCloneBmp->GetHBITMAP( Gdiplus::Color( 255 , 255 , 255 ) , &result );
}

delete( gdiZoomedLoaded );

gdiZoomedLoaded = pCloneBmp;

delete pGraphics;

return result;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated :-)

**EDIT:** Here is how I load the image

```
gdiOrgLoaded = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile( pFilePath , false );
gdiZoomedLoaded = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile( pFilePath , false );

HBITMAP result; // <-- This is bmpLoaded
gdiZoomedLoaded->GetHBITMAP( Gdiplus::Color( 255 , 255 , 255 ) , &result );
```

Comment: you not show where/how you open file. if `old_bmp` open file - you need delete it too

Comment: Ah sorry, I added it in the question. `old_bmp` is `gdiOrgLoaded` in this case.

Comment: It is just a plain bug, you lost the original pCloneBmp pointer value with the assignment.  Since you did not delete it, you have a memory leak with the most visible side-effect that the file doesn't get closed.  Use another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did figure it out. It was indeed some memory leak as @HansPassant suggested.

This is now my working function. I managed to shorten it a lot, too.

```
HBITMAP scale_image( Gdiplus::Bitmap *old_bmp , int x , int y , int width , int height , float scale )
{
HBITMAP result = NULL;
int newWidth = width * scale;
int newHeight = height * scale;

Gdiplus::Bitmap* newBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap( newWidth , newHeight , old_bmp->GetPixelFormat( ) );
Gdiplus::Graphics *pGraphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage( newBitmap );
pGraphics->DrawImage( old_bmp , 0 , 0 , newWidth , newHeight );

delete( gdiZoomedLoaded );

gdiZoomedLoaded = newBitmap;

delete pGraphics;

return result;
}
```